# Programmatically Cancel Running Query in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm able to capture a click on a "Cancel" button while an Access Query is running.  I would like to then be able to cancel the Query.  Is there any way to programmatically (via VBA) cancel a running Query in Access?

Even if I could send a Ctrl-Break to cancel the Query, that would cause an error message box to pop up (with "Code Execution Has Been Interrupted"), which I don't want.

Comment: Don't think you can !

Comment: Why would you want this? Can you not bypass the query for some reason?

Comment: What does "bypass the query" mean?

Comment: For instance, if you're running a set of queries through VBA (as an example), if you don't want one of the queries to run, just remove it or comment it out. If for some reason you're not doing that, why run the query in the first place? If your issue is that the query is taking too long or something, a normal query can be aborted with `ESC`.

Comment: If I wanted to do that, I wouldn't have asked this question.  Some of the Queries I have to run can take a long time.

Comment: I believe sending an `<Esc>` key will halt the query. If you're doing it in code you'll still probably need to trap for Error - Resume Next - or at least turn off warnings before